# Handlebars nested variables/objects, can't reach variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I want to reach a variable two levels up:

```
{{myvariable}}
{{#each grandparent}}
  {{#each parent}}
    {{#customhelper}}
      //i want to reach the variable here
      //{{log ../myvariable}} does not work (returns undefined)
      //{{log .../myvariable}} does not work (returns undefined)
      //{{log ..../myvariable}} does not work (returns undefined)
    {{/customhelper}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

How should I get that? Probably I have some name collisions because the name of the variable is "locale" and that is also a language management variable.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the variable using this syntax:

```
{{../../myvariable}}
```

I don't know if it's the right way. If someone has more information i would like it.

Comment: This is correct. We need to specify `../` path segment per loop for reaching variable outside loop. Since you need to go two levels up (two loop), `../../` would be the path segment.